# 2 Materials with the same image and UV offset for meshes give different results?

Tags: materials, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to combine 2 textures into one, and I successfully put the images together, however while the UVs for the face colour and Hair are in the same place overlaying the same spot, it messes up the face.

[image: Not glitched]

[image: Glitched]

NOTE: While the images only show the Hair UVs, I did change the skin as well, getting the more messed up result.

Comment: I don't understand what you're showing there. The first screenshot shows there is an object called "Hair" and you've put a material called "Hair" on it. The next screenshot shows you have replaced the "Hair" material with a material called "Face". The UVs might be in the same spot, but you cannot put two materials in the same spot of the mesh. And especially not if you remove one material and replace it with the other.

Comment: How so? And is there a way I can combine the textures of the Face and Skin/Hair?

Comment: It's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem (remember to pack the relevant image textures into the blend). The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: @DPadderz To put more than one material on a mesh, first add those materials to the object in the _Material Properties_, i.e. if there's only one material, you only have one material on the object. To add more, create more material slots with the '+' button next to the material's name, then choose a material from the dropdown menu below or hit the 'New' button to create a new one. Then those materials have to be assigned to selected faces in _Edit Mode_. To have different textures etc. on the same face of an object, you have to mix them inside the material which is assigned to the face.

Comment: @DPadderz But I would highly recommend going through some tutorials on how you basically put materials on objects in Blender, and texturing etc.